# 現在URLがサブドメインの時に、PHPでドメインを取得したい

Tags: php

現在URLが
https://a.example.com/
の時も、
https://b.example.com/
の時も、example.comを取得するためには、どうすればよいですか？

定義済みの変数[$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/reserved.variables.server.php)からは取得できない？

Comment: `a.example.com` と `b.example.com` と `example.com` で IP アドレスが異なる場合とか、そもそも DNS ラウンドロビンしてる時とか、状況次第で解決困難になったり無意味だったりするので、もうちょっと状況を限定しないと回答つかないでしょう。要求次第ですが `substr` でも十分だったりするとか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP Domain Parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser) というパッケージがあるようです。

**使い方の例:**
[PHPでドメイン名とサブドメインを分離する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/okakam/items/adfe5b1bd0ce00ca29e4)

> ```php
> $pslManager = new Pdp\PublicSuffixListManager();
> $parser = new Pdp\Parser($pslManager->getList());
>
> $url = 'www.domainname.net';
> $subdomain = $parser->getSubdomain($url);
> $domainName = $parser->getRegisterableDomain($url);
>
> /** $subdomain = 'www' */
> /** $domainName = 'domainname.net' */
> ```